# How to link a cocoapods cordova plugin src to a .framework header file when there's multiple xcode projects in the workspace?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova, cocoapods

The unique situation is that this is an Ionic app that pulls in the uncompiled plugin source via pods. The problem is that when compiling, the plugin headers and implementation can't find the .framework's headers/implementation. The demo Cordova app finds the .framework, but they're only in a single project.

I've tried all the suggestions for "header file not found".

- Adding the .framework to the linked libraries of either the pods project or the app project
- Adding search paths to every target, every app (and combinations thereof)
- Adding a linked binary
- Adding headers/sources to build phases
- add `s.vendored_frameworks = 'ValidicMobile.framework` to the podspec and doing `pod update`

What might be the next thing to try? Would wrapping the vendor .framework in a cocoapod help the plugin find the framework, assuming pods would be better at linking? The plugin requires the import of the other Cordova frameworks in the pods, so not sure if I can put the src directly in the main app or not.

[image: project strucuture]

[image]

Comment: Could you show the podspec of the private library and podfile of App project?

Comment: I think it is against policy. However, it is using the standard ionic+capacitor way of wrapping cordova plugins (so the podfile etc. are generated). I did find a hacky solution in the comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's applicable for your scenario, but way back I did post processing of the PCH file for one of my pods in the `podfile`.

```
    platform :ios, '7.0'
    pod 'A','7.4.1'
    pod 'B', '0.3.1-beta2'
    pod 'C', '0.6.5'

    post_install do | installer |
       print "Updating #{installer.sandbox.target_support_files_root}/Pods-A/A.pch\n"
       open("#{installer.sandbox.target_support_files_root}/Pods-A/A.pch","a") do |file|
       file.puts <<EOF
//your extra stuff goes here
#import "../../../A/Hacks/someExtraHeader1.h"
#import "../../../A/Hacks/someExtraHeader2.h"
EOF
       end
    end
```

That allowed me to inject extra header imports on pod level during `pod install` after all the sources of the pods have already been checked out.

Comment: I actually didn't end up modifying the precompiled headers, but after knowing that physical paths were allowed in pch, I was able to modify the plugin's imports to relative path as listed above. Then I had to link the framework, and in my pod's cordova plugin target, had to set *Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules Yes* in build config. The framework itself, I was able to leave the imports as globals <Library/LibraryThing.h>. But, the catch was that I had to write a script to manually copy the framework into the Derived Data subdirectory. Not sure if there's a way around this step.