# Mixing Swift and Objective C in Dependencies (cocoapods) that work as framework as well as static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

Is it possible to have a pod that can work as framework as well as a static library (depending on the App that want's to use it)?

Basically the problem is that *Module*-Swift.h needs to be included with

```
#import <Module/Module-Swift.h>
```

when used as a framework and

```
#import "Module-Swift.h"
```

when used as a static library.

I haven't found a way to tell the Pod projects where to look to find the header if it can't find the variant I used.

If you want to see the problem in action feel free to check out https://github.com/cweymann/MixedLog-Demo/tree/as_framework
(run setup.sh in the Example subfolder)

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if it's applicable to your case, but check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885148/5329717