# Is there a way to conditionally define a Podspec property depending on static or dynamic usage?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm including a Swift source in my CocoaPods library for the first time. For me to get the project to compile, I need to import the generated Swift header into my Objective-C source. This takes two different forms, depending on whether the project is being built as a static library or a dynamic framework:

```
#ifdef BUILT_AS_FRAMEWORK
    #import <UnzipKit/UnzipKit-Swift.h>
#else
    // Used when built as a static library
    #import "UnzipKit-Swift.h"
#endif
```

I'm defining `BUILT_AS_FRAMEWORK` in my Xcode project for development time, but when I lint the library as a dynamic framework, and because I haven't defined that flag in the Podspec, it attempts to resolve the second import, and can't find it.

Is there a way I can define the `BUILT_AS_FRAMEWORK` preprocessor macro, but only if the consuming Podfile doesn't build it as a static library?

I created [issue #9101 in the CocoaPods project](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9101) for this question.

Comment: Maybe will be easier to youse 2 different targets. For each target you can specify pods differently.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256326/mixing-swift-and-objective-c-in-dependencies-cocoapods-that-work-as-framework

Comment: @user28434 Agreed, it is a duplicate. That never got any answers, though. I'm also asking about a specific approach to solve this issue.

Comment: @Gralex I don't understand your suggestion. Define two different targets where?

Comment: @Dov In XCode targets section. [Here is tutor](https://medium.com/@andersongusmao/xcode-targets-with-multiples-build-configuration-90a575ddc687)

Comment: @Gralex Thanks, but I'm very familiar with Xcode. My problem isn't in Xcode, but when consuming the library I wrote as a CocoaPods dependency. I'm looking for a way to modify my Podspec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use an Xcode environment variable (`PACKAGE_TYPE`) in conjunction with a pre-compilation Run Script build phase to dynamically produce a header to import, which in turn makes the correct generated Swift Header import.

### generate-swift-import-header.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

[[ "${PACKAGE_TYPE}" = "com.apple.package-type.wrapper.framework" ]] \
    && SWIFTIMPORT="<${PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME}/${PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME}-Swift.h>" \
    || SWIFTIMPORT="\"${PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME}-Swift.h\""

if [ -z "$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT" ]; then
    PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT=${SOURCE_ROOT}
    echo "Building in Xcode instead of CocoaPods. Overriding PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT with SOURCE_ROOT"
fi

_Import_text="
#ifndef GeneratedSwiftImport_h
#define GeneratedSwiftImport_h

#import ${SWIFTIMPORT}

#endif /* GeneratedSwiftImport_h */
"
echo "$_Import_text" > ${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/Source/GeneratedSwiftImport.h
```

### Podspec update

```rb
s.script_phases = { :name => "Generate UnzipKit Swift Header",
                    :script => "\"${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}\"/Scripts/generate-swift-import-header.sh",
                    :execution_position => :before_compile }
```

### Library source

I replaced my conditional import with this:

```c
#import "GeneratedSwiftImport.h"
```

I also ignored the `GeneratedSwiftImport.h` file in Git.

Comment: looks very promising! one issue though seems to be that cocoapods adds the GeneratedSwiftImport.h to the umbrella header which leads to errors. did you find a way to prevent that?

Comment: That wasn't an issue for me. You can look at my full [Podspec](https://github.com/abbeycode/UnzipKit/blob/e50f71d83d86310341484ba998c80a5fff885c2e/UnzipKit.podspec), since there may be something I was already doing that avoided this. One thing that leaps out at me is specifying `spec.public_header_files` explicitly.

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long but I finally got around to deal with this issue again. I figured out that the problem in my project was that the generated header was considered public and thus added to the umbrella automatically. Also I added the module name to the name of the generated header because I need this solution for various projects. Thanks so much for sharing your solution!

Comment: Just realized that you suggested that being the problem back then... Feel kind of stupid, sorry for that and thanks again for your help. In the mean time I ran into some weired problems again, where `pod lib lint` would run through but `pod repo push` would fail in that script phase because the permission to write the file was denied. Probably because I didn't add it to gitignore. A similar problem was happening on our CI. We ended up using a Subspec to define the property. Not as elegant because the Consumer of the pod has to be aware of this but works so far.